# Calling a lightning component when user clicks on url type cell in lightning:datatable

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-datatable

I have a lightning:datatable which have a few columns. The first column is of type url.

```
<lightning:datatable
     columns = {!v.columns}"
    data="{!v.data}"
    keyField="Id"
      hideCheckboxColumn="true"
    onrowaction="{!c.handleRowAction}" />
```

In the controller,I have defined a column of type url.

```
type: "url",  fieldName: "ConfirmOrder", label: 'Action', typeAttributes: {label: 'Confirm/Reject'}}
```

Now, when a user clicks on the column, then i want to pass recordId and show another lightning:component.

Is it possible in lightning:datatable, as i am not able to do so?

Comment: Are you trying to navigate to a URL-addressable component, or take some other action like presenting a Quick Action or re-rendering portions of your current page?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to navigate to a URL-addressable component.

Comment: to open a different lightning component it is best to use an action or a button type column and not a url, then easily you can take the recordId from the javascript